# Getting Count from Query using Parse is really slow

Tags: c#, parse-platform

I have a Parse service that I am connecting to and I am trying to get some stats from the DB. I have a simple query that I am trying to use to fetch a count but it takes forever.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
var query = from item in new ParseQuery<Thanks> ()
            where item.Get<Person>("postOwner").Equals (ParseObject.CreateWithoutData<Person>(personId))
            select item;

return await query.CountAsync ();
```

Comment: can you clarify takes forever?

Comment: I have waited for a result for 10 minutes and have not received anything

Comment: Could you please share your findings on this? Thx.